# How do I programmatically use the S3FS module?

Tags: 7

I've included S3FS module in Drupal 7. I'm able to store files by using S3FS as a field of a node.

Now, I need to store a file on S3 bucket when a cron job is executed. How can I programmatically use the module?

Comment: I would expect the techniques and maybe helper functions to be in the s3fs module.

Comment: Is there any sample code available to understand the usage of those helper function? I didn't find any so far.

Comment: I'm able to connect to S3 bucket via creating a mount directory by using s3fs-fuse. I was expecting to use some calls or S3FS directly in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command to write the file. The system picks up the S3 connection (as I mentioned earlier that I'm able to store file as a field of a node):

```
file_put_contents('s3://Dir1/output.json', $jsonStr);
```

Comment: This answer is helpful and contains the gist of the solution but needs a bit of expansion. You should explain that the "s3://" prefix is a stream wrapper which allows filesystem operations to be performed transparently on the bucket using standard PHP file functions.

Answer (score 0):

I created this module that copies images, css, js to s3 https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2678270